# Use scanf() to read an unknown number of integers in c

Tags: c, scanf

I need to read an unknown number of rows, each containing an unknown number of integers, this number varying from row to row.

The integers are separated from each other by a single space and there is no space at the end of the line.

The output being the sum of all integers.

exemple input:

```
5
2 2
4 4 4
6 6
3 3
```

output:
`39`

Comment: Read whole lines (using e.g. [`fgets`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fgets)). For each line, in a loop call [`strtol`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strtol) to extract the next integer. If you need to save the values for later processing, use pointers and dynamic allocation (and reallocation).

Comment: However, depending on what you're supposed to do with the numbers, which you don't tell us, then it might be okay to just call `scanf("%d", &number)` in a loop until it returns something different from `1`. Since you don't tell us the underlying problem, what you're supposed to do with the numbers, it's very hard to give you a good single solution.

Comment: @Balou You don't need to pre-read a `rows` number. You need one loop, calling `scanf` to read one `int` as you're doing, checking its return value, and as long the return value is 1, adding the `int` you just read to a running "sum" variable.

Comment: @SteveSummit forget my (now deleted) comment, I misinterpreted the question.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude, I need to return the sum of all the numbers.

Comment: Maybe just using `scanf` until eof and adding the numbers?

Comment: Then just `scanf` in a loop, adding the numbers.

Comment: Do you care about the number of integers in each row?  ie, do you need to distinguish between `1 2 3\n4 5 6\n` and `1\n2 3\n 4\n5\n6`?  It is more difficult with `scanf` if the type of whitespace is relevant.

Comment: @WilliamPursell Yes, at the end of each line "\n" will be used to jump to the following line.

Comment: The *rows and columns* are just a distraction: `int n, sum = 0; while (scanf("%d", &n) == 1) sum += n; printf("sum is %d\n", sum);`

Comment: `scanf` has the -- usually undesirable -- property that it treats all whitespace, both within lines and the newlines at the ends of lines, exactly the same.  However, for this particular problem statement, that's just what's needed.

Comment: Please take some time to refresh [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), take the SO [tour], read [ask], as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). Always include the actual problem you try to solve with your code in the question itself. It would have made it much simpler to know what can be done and how to properly help you.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude, I just edited the question so it is exactly as it is asked on my exercise.

Answer (score 1):

The fact that the numbers are entered over several lines is actually irrelevant. Basically you just want to sum up numbers entered by the user until the input stream ends.

You probably want something like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {    
  int sum = 0;
  int number;

  while (scanf("%d", &number) == 1)
  {
    sum += number;
  }

  printf("Sum of all numbers is %d\n", sum);
}
```

End the input with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd>.

Example of execution:

```
1 2 3
4 5
6 7
8
Sum of all numbers is 36
```

Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> after entering `8`.

**Explanation of `while (scanf("%d", &number) == 1)`**

`scanf` returns the number of items successfully scanned or `EOF` when the input stream ends. So here we decide to stop the loop if `scanf` returns anything else than 1 (meaning that the user has either pressed <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> triggering an EOF, or has entered something that is not a number (e.g. `ABC`).

Comment: On Windows end the input with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd> followed by <kbd>Enter</kbd> on its own line.

Comment: @thebusybee `<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>` doesn't work in comments.

Comment: Yes, I noticed (too late), it's a pity.