# Scanf an unknown amount of integers without using array and printf right away

Tags: c, scanf

(I'm a newbie)
I need to use a loop to `scanf` an unknown amount of integers without using array until <kbd>Ctrl-D</kbd> and printing them as loop goes.
For example, an input can be:

```
140 128 8 1603 
4905 -3 -2 0 0 
9166 255 -1322 
8900 10000 -1 6543
```

in which case output should be:

```
140, 128, 8, 1603, 4905, -3, -2, 0, 0, 9166, 255, -1322, 8900, 10000, -1, 6543
```

Now, when I try to write something like

```
while (scanf("%d", &number)) {
    /* code */
    printf("%d, ", number);
    /* code */
}
```

`scanf` will scan values until it sees a `\n`, then it prints every value it scanned and repeats until <kbd>Ctrl-D</kbd>, which leads to my input mix up with my output like that:

```
140 128 8 1603 
140, 128, 8, 1603, 4905 -3 -2 0 0 
4905, -3, -2, 0, 0, 9166 255 -1322
9166, 255, -1322, 8900 10000 -1 654
```

Could i get some advices on coding techniques of avoiding that and also what in this case could be an optimal check to not printf the last comma?

Comment: Actually, you're doing it the right way.  Your code is almost fine.  Don't worry about that "interleaving"; it's inevitable.  If you want to see "correct" output, put the input data into a file, and run your program with its input redirected to come from that file.  That is, assuming you're invoking from the command line, run `myprogram < inputfile`.

Comment: If you do run your program with its input redirected from a file (or if you type Control-D to terminate interactive input), you're going to find another problem.  `scanf` does *not* return a true/false Boolean success/failure value.  It returns the number of values it successfully converted.  So you want your `while` loop to continue as long as `scanf` returns 1, not as long as it returns something other than 0.  `scanf` returns EOF (a nonzero negative value) when it reaches end-of-file.

Comment: Two ways to not print that last comma: (1) Have a boolean variable `firsttime`.  Initialize it to 1.  Then, each trip through the loop, when you print a number you've just read, don't print the comma after it.  Instead, print the comma *before* it, *but* only if `firsttime` is 1.  Then, set `firsttime` to 0.  Or, (2), have a string variable `sep`.  Initialize it to the empty string.  Each trip through the loop, print `sep` before the number, and then set `sep` to a the string `", "`.

Comment: Alternatively, you can instead redirect the *output* to a file with `myprogram > outputfile`.  That, too, will prevent the output from being intermixed with the input on your screen, and you might find it more convenient to test.

Comment: For an explanation of why you see that "interleaving", see [this course notes chapter](https://www.eskimo.com/~scs/cclass/notes/sx6b.html) (specifically, the paragraph beginning "Finally, don't be disappointed").

Comment: 'scanf will scan values until it sees a \n' is not correct.  'scanf' reads the input until it sees the first character that is not part of an integer.  You terminal, however, is buffering data and not sending anything to your program until you hit 'enter'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is almost correct: should should just test `while (scanf("%d", &number) == 1)` instead of `!= 0` as `scanf()` will return `EOF` at end of file.

You might want to only print the `,` if there is another number. As coded, the output will have a trailing comma. You can do this by printing `", "` *before* each number except the first one.

Your interpretation of the program's behavior is slightly incorrect: the reason `scanf()` seems to convert and retain all values up to the newline is `stdin` is line buffered on your system so input is not available to `scanf()` until a full line of text has been read. Furthermore there is another layer of buffering at the terminal level, so changing the buffering scheme of `stdin` with `setvbuf()` will not suffice if you are reading from a terminal.

Answer (score 0):

A possible approach to not printing the last comma (in this case we print the comma first, unless it is the first element that we scan):

```c
#include <stdio.h> // scanf(), printf()
#include <stdbool.h> // bool, true, false

int main(void) {
  int number;

  bool first_scan = true;
  while (scanf("%d", &number) == 1) {
    if (first_scan != true) {
      printf(", ");
    }
    printf("%d", number);
    first_scan = false;
  }
  printf("\n");

  return 0;
}
```

If you write a file `test.txt` containing:

```
1 2 3
4 5 6
```

And you run your program like this:

```
./program < test.txt
```

You get this output:

```
1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6
```

---

NOTE: `scanf()` isn't well suited for this purpose, because it will not detect integer overflows (and it will also give you a lot headaches), so it is generally good practice to [avoid it](http://sekrit.de/webdocs/c/beginners-guide-away-from-scanf.html). An alternative approach in this case would be using `fgets()` and `strtoll()`, but it is out of the scope of this answer.

EDIT: my previous note was quite ambiguous (thanks, Steve Summit): when I say "`scanf()` isn't well suited for this", I mean "isn't suited for reading integers in a real-world application", but for beginning programs like yours, it's fine. However, when you become more comfortable with C (and you start writing more complex applications), you should take a look at `fgets()` and `strtoll()` (not yet, if you're not ready), so you can write more correct programs.

Comment: I have to disagree with your last NOTE.  I know where you're coming from, but: (1) for better or worse, `scanf` is what every beginning C programmer is taught and is more or less compelled to use, and this problem is actually the one (rather unique) purpose that `scanf` actually *is* well-suited for! (2) Your assertion that `scanf` is unsuited and should be avoided, and your allusion to an alternative approach, is sort of an unfair teaser, because that approach is, as you say, out of scope here.  For this particular problem statement, I don't believe that `fgets`+`strtoll` is preferable.

Comment: @SteveSummit (1) I get what you mean (`scanf()` is well-suited for toy programs like this one), and that's why I put it into a note (i.e.: "your program is not wrong, this is just a note"). When I say "scanf() is not well-suited for this" I just mean "for parsing integers in general". I have seen so many (many!) bugs and vulnerabilities in production-code because of reasons like these, so I tend to teach people from the very beginning not to use `scanf()`. (2) My "teaser" suggestion is just a remainder that when the OP will start writing "real" code, they should research those two functions.

Comment: @SteveSummit Anyway, I edited my answer to make it more clear. Thanks very much. (And sorry if I may have strong opinions on some topics, it's just the force of habit, I guess.)

Comment: @LucaPolito Thanks for your second Note, and as I said, I do understand where you're coming from!  `scanf` sucks, for almost every application there is, other than the contrived one in this question (and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69403952), just yesterday), and I very dearly wish that beginning programmers didn't have to "learn" (i.e. waste time on) it at all.  In my introductory C programming course at https://www.eskimo.com/~scs/cclass/ I tried to teach C from the beginning without `scanf`; I'm not sure how well I succeeded.

Comment: @SteveSummit Not to be O/T, but I did see your class notes and they are quite good indeed. IMHO, the key in teaching without using `scanf()` is to provide a pre-made function to students (e.g.: `read_int_from_stdin()`) and later, when students are good enough, you ask them to write that function themselves. I consider `scanf()` like I consider `K&R 1st edition`: you *must* know it from top to bottom to consider yourself a C programmer, *but* only when you have enough experience, not as a learning tool.